# Replace Invalid Email Format with a Valid One

Tags: if-statement, replace, powerquery

In Power Query, I have a list of emails that includes invalid emails. I am looking to use M codes to identify and "fix" them. For example, my email list would include something like "1234.my_email_gmail_com@error.invalid.com"

I am looking for Power Query to find similar email addresses, then produce an output of a valid email. For the example above, it should be "my_email@gmail.com"

Essentially, I want to do the following:

- Remove the digits at the front (number of digits varies)
- Remove the "@error.invalid.com"
- Replace the first underscore "_" from the right to "."
- Replace the second underscore "_" from the right to "@"

I'm still new to Power Query, especially with M codes. I appreciate any help and guidance I can get.

Comment: Look for something called fuzzy match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the function `cleanEmailAddress` below:

```
let
    cleanEmailAddress = (invalidEmailAddress as text) as text =>
        let
            removeLeadingNumbers = Text.AfterDelimiter(invalidEmailAddress, "."), // Assumes invalid numbers are followed by "." which itself also needs removing.
            removeInvalidDomain = Text.BeforeDelimiter(removeLeadingNumbers, "@"),
            replaceLastOccurrence = (someText as text, oldText as text, newText as text) as text =>
                let
                    lastPosition = Text.PositionOf(someText, oldText, Occurrence.Last),
                    replaced = if lastPosition >= 0 then Text.ReplaceRange(someText, lastPosition, Text.Length(oldText), newText) else someText
                in replaced,
            overwriteTopLevelDomainSeparator = replaceLastOccurrence(removeInvalidDomain, "_", "."),
            overwriteAtSymbol = replaceLastOccurrence(overwriteTopLevelDomainSeparator, "_", "@")
        in overwriteAtSymbol,
    cleaned = cleanEmailAddress("1234.my_email_gmail_com@error.invalid.com")
in
    cleaned
```

Regarding:

> - *"Remove the digits at the front (number of digits varies)"*

Your question doesn't mention what to do with the leading `.` (which remains if you remove the leading digits), but your expected output (`"my_email@gmail.com"`) suggests it should be removed. Email addresses which do not have `.` immediately after the leading digits, will return an error (and the logic for `removeLeadingNumbers` expression will need to be improved).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the leading "." after the digits should be removed as well. Being a noob in Power Query, I copied your code above and replaced the "1234.my_email_gmail_com@error.invalid.com" with the email column. For most valid email addresses, they returned "com" or something similar. I thought I can work with that to help me identify which ones I need to fix, but I then realized valid emails such as "valid.email@ymail.com" would return as "email". Any suggestion on how to avoid this?

Comment: It's OK, I was able to use Conditional column to only display valid email addresses, following up from your formula above. If you do have codes that can help, I'll gladly accept. However, I was just able to manipulate the data to get the final output I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work too:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Valid", each Text.ReplaceRange(Text.ReplaceRange(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],".","@"),Text.PositionOf(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],".","@"),"_",Occurrence.Last),1,"."),Text.PositionOf(Text.ReplaceRange(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],".","@"),Text.PositionOf(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],".","@"),"_",Occurrence.Last),1,"."),"_",Occurrence.Last),1,"@"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```